# How can I enable SSO across two apps in different Azure AD B2C tenants?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

App-1 will have the user log-in/sign-up with social accounts (Azure AD B2C), App-2 will only be accessed by authenticated users in App-1

Each App is in a different AD tenant

Answer (score 0):

For SSO, both applications need to be protected against the same Azure AD B2C instance/tenant. You do not need to configure anything to get SSO between the apps, that is default behavior.

If you want to use two different tenants, and the user will always be logged into App1 or App2 before going to the other app, then you could use id_token_hint to generate a magic link from App1 to access App2 protected by a different tenant.
Concept is detailed here:
https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/tree/master/policies/invite

Comment: thanks @Jas Suri - MSFT, I am interested in two different tenants scenario with seamless SSO, (meaning once logged in to 1 app, no need to enter credentials in app-2 or setup an account). The link you provided seems to assume the user has to be invited and setup an account in App-2. 
This seems to be the closest I can find but running into troubles to make it work in Angular: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/identity-provider-azure-ad-b2c?pivots=b2c-custom-policy

Comment: After the user logs into App 1, and clicks App 2 link, App 1 makes API call to generate an id_token_hint. App 1 then makes a request to `app2.com?hint=id_token_hint_value`. App 2 sends the user to B2C which processes the id_token_hint and logs the user into this tenant and app without asking for creds (SSO). The sample demonstrates a use case, but the concept can be used in any way.